# Display value of custom field at the beginning of a post

Tags: posts, customization

I've been using the subtitles plugin to display a teaser text to my posts right underneath the title (which is named `_subtitle`, and stored in the post's meta).

How do I display this value at the `post_content`'s beginning?

Comment: Plugin recommendations are offtopic here, I've ammended your question to remove this and improve the readability

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepend value stored in `_subtitle` to the content of the post so that it works. Please place following code in your theme's functions.php file and it shall work. Please let me know how it goes so that I may assist further:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_subtitle_to_content' );
function prepend_subtitle_to_content( $content ){
    $subtitle = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_subtitle', true );
    if ( !empty( $subtitle ) ) {
        return esc_html( $subtitle ) . $content ;
   }
   return $content;
}
```

Comment: `get_post_meta` should be wrapped in an escaping function, that subtitle could be anything from "Hello world" to "<script>......"

Comment: That should be escaping not sanitising, e.g. `wp_kses_post` or `esc_html`, you sanitize and validate on input, you escape on output. Your code also doesnt return the content when the `_subtitle` meta isn't present

Comment: Ah.. Thanks for inputs and edits Tom. That adds to my knowledge. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello - and sorry for breaking the rules. Thanks Tom and especially to ItsMePN for helping out on this one anyway, I really appreaciate it. This is actually working if the value (subtitle) is present - while this is helping out on a displaying-basis I'd really like to know how to combine the value (of a custom field from the post_meta) with the post_content inside of the wordpress database (and save the newly combined value). I hope this is not too off topic (again). Thanks a lot! Cheers!